# Bootstrap modal not displayed but seems to be opened

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

So I'm trying to add bootstrap modals to display certain details about my projects on my portfolio page.

But for some reason the modal doesn't show anything. When I inspect element it covers the whole page.

My relevant code is:

The trigger:

```
<a class="projectbox" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
```

The modal:

```
                    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

A live preview of what happens can be found here (Click on the android logo):

[Live Preview (Click on android logo)](https://mrdylan123.github.io/portfolio/)

If there is any information missing please let me know.

Also, I have included JQuery before bootstrap js:

```
<!-- Import js -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Above code is at the bottom of my index page.

The code can be found here:

[Source code](https://github.com/mrdylan123/portfolio)

> What seems to have been my problem was not having the .in class in my
>   modal. My first line of the modal now looks like this:
>
> ```
> <div class="modal fade in bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
> ```
>
> and it works.

Comment: When I inspect your modal, there is nothing inside of it but '`...`' ?

Comment: Correct. But shouldn't it look like this?:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-sizes

Comment: Correct. Your modal code is invalid.

Comment: What part makes it invalid? I copied the code from the 'large' example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your modal is getting a class of `.show` added to it when you should be adding a class of `.in`.

Copying the bootstrap examples isn't the best as they tend to be stripped back versions... they assume you copied the default example at the top of the section. If you want to copy a specific version, such as the large modal then I'd recommend you use the default modal and modify it accordingly based off the 'large' example.

```
<div class="modal fade in bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would also recommend moving the modal code to the very bottom of the page above the `</body>` tag but above the `<script>` tags. This will help prevent any potential conflicts.

Comment: It appears adding the .in class fixed my problem. Now the only problem is it doesnt seem to be animated, in the example pages it slides down on opening and slides up on closing.

Answer (score 0):

hey I think the problem is because of your trigger part

```
{<a class="projectbox" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">}
```

i have looked into gist and your  captures a lot of images and stuff (thus making it capture the whole page), and you are missing to give one definite element which should be clicked in order to open the modal, 
a better version would be-

```
<button  class="projectbox btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" >Modal Button</button>
```

everything else after closing the button

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

that's the standard
but if you wanna make one of the pictures as trigger element (as it seemed to me) then 
`<a class="projectbox" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"><img src="">
</a>`
then everything else here,
hope it helps

Comment: I tried making a button for it, it didn't change the way it acts. The same problem still occurs.

Comment: hey sorry my code part wasn't visible before,the problem is that you are closing your trigger <a> to late, and it is containing the whole block(at least that's what i think)

Comment: Hey, no worries. I have managed to fix it, however I'm not sure how. The only problem i'm facing now is that it doesn't fade in or slide down or anything. There seems to be no animation.

Comment: Actually, adding the .in class to my modal seems to be what fixed my initial problem. Still no animations though.